# Increment value in table rows

Tags: javascript

How to increment value in table rows with each row having different values?
This is like a calendar. I have declared month and year and the first row is the days. So the second row will start from 2 because the month is set at 1 and the month + day - 1 + 1 = 2 and it will go until the last cell like 2,3,4,5,6. The third row will be from 21-25 because i want to sum month+day+last two digits of year - 1+1+19. I managed to find the table and increment but it goes down instead of right.

```js
$('#table').find('td:nth-child(1)').each(function(i) {
  var month = 1;
  var y1 = 2019;
  var y2 = 12;
  var y3 = 19;
  $(this).text(i + month);
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="Month">Month: 1</h2>
  <span id="Year">Year: 2019</span>
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ```<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>``` should be inside the <head> tag, not at the top of the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean some thing like this? I've add a **thead** and **tbody** element to easy select the rows. Then i take the whole first row and with in this i take all the cells nd ste the text. Hope it helps.

```js
var year = 2019;
var month = 1;

$('#Month').text('Month: '+month);
$('#Year').text('Year: '+year);

for(var i=1; i<=$('#table thead th').length; ++i){
  var day = parseInt($('#table thead th:nth-child('+i+')').text());
  $('#table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child('+i+')').text(day);
  $('#table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child('+i+')').text(day+month);
  $('#table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child('+i+')').text(day+month+(year%100));
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

thead {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="Month"></h2>
  <span id="Year"></span>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    </body>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not really. It's like adding the month + day or year. The month has value of 1 and the first row represents days. So the second row should be 2-6 because Month(1)+day(1-5) = 2 and then continues until last cell under 5 = 6. The third row will be like adding month + day + last two digits of year - 19. So it should be from 21-25.
Under first row - 12345 should be 2,3,4,5,6 and under second row should be 21,22,23,24,25 because i want to have different incrementation. Get it? The second row is sum of 1+the number from first row and the third row is 1+numbers from first row.

Comment: here is an example: http://knowledgeispower.bg.cm/calendar.html
The red row counts the month + day, the first brown row under numerology counts month+day+1+9. The second brown row counts same thing but reduces the value to a single digit or counts the double digits of first brown row.

Comment: I've changed the code. You can add more calculation inside the for-loop with the given syntax if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this - iterating through rows and inside them through columns:

```js
var j = 0;
$('#table tr').each(function(i) {
  $(this).find("td").each( function() {
  j++;
  var month = 1;
  var y1 = 2019;
  var y2 = 12;
  var y3 = 19;
  $(this).text(j + month);
  })

})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 id="Month">Month: 1</h2>
  <span id="Year">Year: 2019</span>
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here's example: http://knowledgeispower.bg.cm/calendar.html
The red row counts the month+day - 1+1 = 2, 1+2 = 3 and so on.
The first brown row under numerology counts the month+day+(1+9)
The third brown row counts the month+day+(2+0+1+9).
I trying to do that. In my case i want to make the third row count month+day+19
and each row will have different starting value.